# How to detect wether the mouse is over the :before or over the :after part of an element

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, pseudo-element

I have this CSS to define drop areas, where a user can either drop a section before or after existing sections.

```
.section:before,
.section:after {
    content: "[insert here]";
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 3px dashed #aaa;
}
```

Using JavaScript + JQuery here is the drop listener, that detects the element currently under the mouse:

```
elem.on('drop', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault();

  var container = $(elem[0].elementFromPoint(e.clientX, e.clientY));
});
```

However `container` would be the same element for both the :before and :after case.

How will I be able to know if the user has dropped before or after the section?

Comment: Of course. Because `:before` and `:after` are sort of "inside" the same container.

Comment: You should use real elements if you want to handle DOM events, rather than pseudo-elements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### This is actually possible.

(Although - as others have mentioned - probably not the the best idea)

Assuming that the content is stacked one above the other with: before -> content -> after

We can calculate the dropping point with respect to the container and then - based on the height of the generated content we can determine if the element was dropped in the before or after zone.

And yes, [javascript can actually access css properties of pseudo-elements](https://davidwalsh.name/ways-css-javascript-interact).

This is done with `Window.getComputedStyle()`

Syntax: (from [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/getComputedStyle))

```
var style = window.getComputedStyle(element[, pseudoElt]);
```

> pseudoElt Optional
>
> A string specifying the pseudo-element to match.
>   Must be omitted (or null) for regular elements.

So, for example, to get the height of the generated content before the section (let's call it 'target'):

```
window.getComputedStyle(target, ':before').height
```

### Here's a Demo snippet:

```js
var elem = document.getElementById("el");
var target = document.getElementById("target");
  
var targetHeight = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(target).height);
var beforeHeight = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(target, ':before').height);
var afterHeight = parseFloat(window.getComputedStyle(target, ':after').height);

elem.addEventListener("drag", function(e) {
  document.body.classList.remove('dropped');
});

target.addEventListener("dragover", function(e) {
  this.textContent = "dragging over section";
  document.body.classList.add('dragging-over');
  addBeforeAfterClasses(e);
});

target.addEventListener("dragleave", function(e) {
  document.body.classList.remove('dragging-over');
  this.textContent = "section";
  e.currentTarget.style.background = "none";
});

target.addEventListener("drop", function(e) {
  document.body.classList.add('dropped');
  addBeforeAfterClasses(e);
  this.textContent = "successfully dropped!";
});

function addBeforeAfterClasses(e) {
  var dropOffsetTopWithRespectToContainer = e.clientY - target.offsetTop;
  if(dropOffsetTopWithRespectToContainer <= beforeHeight) {
    document.body.classList.add('before');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('before');
  }
  if(dropOffsetTopWithRespectToContainer > targetHeight - beforeHeight) {
    document.body.classList.add('after');
  } else {
    document.body.classList.remove('after');
  }
}

target.ondrop = drop_handler;
target.ondragover = dragover_handler;

function drop_handler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}

function dragover_handler(e) {
  e.preventDefault();
}
```

```css
.section {
  margin: 10px;
  position: relative;
}
.section:before,
.section:after {
    content: "[insert here]";
    height: 64px;
    line-height: 56px;
    width: 100%;
    display: block;
    border: 3px dashed #aaa;
}

.dragging-over.before .section:before {
  content: "[drop into before]";
  border-color: green;
}

.dragging-over.after .section:after {
  content: "[drop into after]";
  border-color: green;
}

.dropped.before .section:before {
  content: "[dropped into before]";
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.dropped.after .section:after {
  content: "[dropped into after]";
  background-color: green;
  color: white;
}

.elem {
  width: 20px;
  height: 20px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  background-color: maroon;
  margin: 0 20px;
  display: inline-block;
}
```

```html
<div id="target" class="section">section</div>
<span>drag me:</span>
<div id="el" draggable="true" class="elem"></div>
```

### [Codepen demo](https://codepen.io/danield770/pen/dJzYQq)

Answer (score 3):

`::before` and `::after` are css pseudo-elements which javascript do not know about. For javascript, they are both their parent element.

You might want to use real html elements to do that.

Answer (score 2):

:before and :after are not part of the DOM, hence they are not accessible to any Javascript.

However the only solution I can think of is to calculate the height of the section and then compare it with the drop x and y coordinates to determine whether it was dropped before or after.

Comment: Comparing the mouse position the the element positions actually works indeed. (e.clientY <= elem[0].getBoundingClientRect().top + 64)? 'before' : 'after'; Thanks for that idea. However I agree that it might be better to use actual DOM elements.

Comment: Cheers :) Yup that is a better idea. My answer was just incase you need to do it this way due to some constraints

Answer (score 2):

I think you can not manipulate the pseudo elements `::before` and `::after`, as technically there are not DOM and therefore is inaccessible by any JavaScript.